# How to specify which webhook to be used when using same stripe account on 2 websites?

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to use 1 stripe account on 2 different websites (2 different domain names).

I can add 2 webhooks. But how can I specify

> site1.com -> use webhook1
>
> site2.com -> use webhook2

(I use standard php lib)

Comment: webhook for which event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do this using a single account, you should use instead multiple accounts,
[https://stripe.com/docs/account/multiple-accounts#:~:text=You%20must%20use%20separate%20Stripe%20accounts%20for%20projects%2C%20websites%2C%20or%20businesses%20that%20operate%20independently%20from%20one%20another](https://stripe.com/docs/account/multiple-accounts#:%7E:text=You%20must%20use%20separate%20Stripe%20accounts%20for%20projects%2C%20websites%2C%20or%20businesses%20that%20operate%20independently%20from%20one%20another)

For each account (that represents a website in your case), you can separately configure the webhook settings to use different endpoints